# Activity of YoutubeFragment has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube

### YoutubeFragment

Hi all,

my application works fine, I saw the video from youtube but when I change the orientation, I keep seeing the video but the log gives me that error of leak ServiceConnection.

```
public class PlayerYouTubeFrag extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    public PlayerYouTubeFrag() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String currentVideoID = "wKJ9KzGQq0w";
    private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

    private int section_id;
   private Realm realm;
    public static PlayerYouTubeFrag newInstance(int section_id) {

    PlayerYouTubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYouTubeFrag();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("section_id", section_id);

        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    private void init() {
        initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                player.setFullscreenControlFlags(0);

                if (!wasRestored) {
                    activePlayer = player;
                    //activePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                    activePlayer.loadVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
                    activePlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                    YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                Log.i("YouTube faillure", "Provider "+arg0.toString()+" YouTubeInitializationResult "+arg1.ordinal());
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
       init();
      return super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        activePlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            section_id = getArguments().getInt("section_id");
            Section section = realm.where(Section.class).equalTo("id_s",section_id).findFirst();
            // appController.getSectionsDao().queryForId(section_id);
            if (section.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
                String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|v\\/|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*"; // "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*" // "\b(?<=v.|/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11,}\b"
                Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(section.getRoot_url());

              if(matcher.find())
                {
                    currentVideoID = matcher.group();
                }
            }
        }
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).extras = getArguments();

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }    

}
```

### Error of logCat

> Activity com.euphor.paperpad.activities.main.MainActivity has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@2bc2136c that was
>   originally bound here
>                                                                        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity
>   com.euphor.paperpad.activities.main.MainActivity has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@2bc2136c that was
>   originally bound here
>                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1077)
>                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
>                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1782)
>                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1765)
>                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                            at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                            at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                            at
>   com.euphor.paperpad.activities.fragments.PlayerYouTubeFrag.onCreateView(PlayerYouTubeFrag.java:105)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I loof for a solution before posting my question what I found is not working for me and I add the release in onPause but whithout result.

Thank's.

Comment: "what I found is not working for me" Can you say what you found, and in what way it doesn't work for you?

Comment: "I add the release in onPause but whithout result."

Comment: Can you say where you found the suggestion to use this? And what does "without result" mean?

Comment: first, thank's for your time, I mean that even I added the release of player when I change the orientation I got the same error : app works fine but the log cat gives me the error, I found it in stack but not the same situation, hope u give me some help here If you wany

Comment: Not really, I'm not familiar enough with the android lifecycle. All I can say is that it looks like you have a code path where the reference is not being released.

Comment: not problem, anyway thank's for your time, have a nice day sir